# performance of functions and memory allocated in c#

Tags: c#, clr

I would like to see each and every function performance
and the memory allocated to it.
so that i can make my function run faster in c#.
Is there any such type of profile is there to watch out the memory allocated to each function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### CLR profiler

One of the important factors for performance degradation in .NET code is memory consumption. Many developers just concentrate on execution time to determine performance bottle necks in a .NET application. Only measuring execution time does not clearly give idea of where the performance issue resides.
The execution time can be clearly viewed

[here is the link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/45292/NET-Best-Practice-No-1-Detecting-High-Memory-cons) where you can find complete details ...

hope this helps ...

Answer (score 0):

I think Microsoft's .NET performance tools has [feature that you require](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms242740%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a utility from `SysInternals` that help identify the memory usage per each process...
[RamMap](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/ff700229)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do memory profiling of your application. Below mentioned discussion may help you about that

[What Are Some Good .NET Profilers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3927/what-are-some-good-net-profilers)